# Can I use threads to change a GTK image?

Tags: c, multithreading, image, gtk

I have a GTK window with an image inside of it. I want this image to change. Let's say I have two images, "sun.png" and "moon.png". Once every second, I want to receieve the output of "date -f%l" to get the current hour. If the hour is between 7-19 (7 AM to 7 PM), I want to display sun.png. Else, I want to display moon.png.

Is it possible to have a seperate thread with a while loop in it, that changes the image as the program's running? How would I go about doing this?

I'm writing in C, by the way.

Comment: another option would be to use alarm(), which sends a SIGALRM signal after the specified number of seconds. Keep in mind though, that signals are often frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to be a complete answer, but it's too long for a comment and it's important.

You definitely do not implement something like this by going into a loop sleeping for one second at a time and calling the external `date` command and parsing its output to determine what to do next. Not only is this a lot more work than is necessary; more importantly, it will eat your users' batteries for dinner.

Instead, you call `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime` to determine the current time, then compute the next time in the future that the sun/moon image will need to be changed. Then, you sleep the whole interval until that time, i.e. up to 12 hours in a single sleep. If your thread wakes up early (perhaps from signals, etc.) then you just determine, on calling `gettimeofday` again, that it's not yet time to change, and compute a new duration of time to go back to sleep. This way, the CPU remains completely idle (and can go into powersaving mode) except when there's actually work to be done.

As for whether you can do this with a thread at all in GTK+, I'm pretty sure you can, but I'm not familiar with the GTK+ API.

Comment: I know it would be easier to use `gettimeofday`, the situation I described was just an example. The program I'm planning to write is more complicated.